# Error installing npm module 'underscore' on raspi3

Tags: node.js, npm, underscore.js, raspberry-pi3

in my project folder I run

```
npm install underscore
```

the install begins and then it aborts with the following

```
    pi@mserv01:~/foo $ npm install underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/-/underscore-1.8.3.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/-/underscore-1.8.3.tgz
abort: +▒▒
▒▒▒\ ▒▒<

==== Stack trace ============================================

Security context: 0x32434659 <JS Object>#0#
    1: _parse(aka parse) [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/extended-header.js:~61] (this=0x5d74cbad <an ExtendedHeader>#1#,c=0x5d74fca1 <a Buffer>#2#)
    2: emit [events.js:95] (this=0x5d74cbad <an ExtendedHeader>#1#,type=0x4dc14839 <String[4]: data>)
    3: arguments adaptor frame: 2->1
    4: _read [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/entry.js:111] (this=0x5d74cbad <an ExtendedHeader>#1#)
    8: _read [native v8natives.js:1594] (this=0x5d74cbad <an ExtendedHeader>#1#)
    9: write [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/entry.js:68] (this=0x5d74cbad <an ExtendedHeader>#1#,c=0x5d74fca1 <a Buffer>#2#)
   10: _process [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:104] (this=0x5d738181 <an Extract>#3#,c=0x5d74fca1 <a Buffer>#2#)
   11: /* anonymous */ [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:46] (this=0x5d738379 <a BlockStream>#4#,c=0x5d74fca1 <a Buffer>#2#)
   12: emit [events.js:95] (this=0x5d738379 <a BlockStream>#4#,type=0x4dc14839 <String[4]: data>)
   13: arguments adaptor frame: 2->1
   14: _emitChunk [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/block-stream/block-stream.js:145] (this=0x5d738379 <a BlockStream>#4#,flush=0x32408091 <undefined>)
   15: arguments adaptor frame: 0->1
   16: resume [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/block-stream/block-stream.js:58] (this=0x5d738379 <a BlockStream>#4#)
   17: arguments adaptor frame: 1->0
   18: resume [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/reader.js:253] (this=0x5d738181 <an Extract>#3#,who=0x5d738181 <an Extract>#3#)
   19: arguments adaptor frame: 0->1
   20: /* anonymous */ [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:256] (this=0x5d74486d <an Entry>#5#)
   21: emit [events.js:92] (this=0x5d74486d <an Entry>#5#,type=0x4dc164b9 <String[6]: resume>)
   22: resume [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/entry.js:92] (this=0x5d74486d <an Entry>#5#)
   23: resume [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/collect.js:62] (this=0x32434701 <JS Global Object>#6#)
   24: unblockEntry [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/collect.js:43] (this=0x32434701 <JS Global Object>#6#)
   25: /* anonymous */ [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/collect.js:47] (this=0x5d74486d <an Entry>#5#,dest=0x5d7477c5 <a FileWriter>#7#)
   26: /* anonymous */ [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:143] (this=0x5d7477c5 <a FileWriter>#7#)
   27: emit [events.js:92] (this=0x5d7477c5 <a FileWriter>#7#,type=0x530a276d <String[5]: ready>)
   28: /* anonymous */ [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/file-writer.js:45] (this=0x5d74a615 <a WriteStream>#8#,fd=10)
   29: emit [events.js:95] (this=0x5d74a615 <a WriteStream>#8#,type=0x4dc1f615 <String[4]: open>)
   30: arguments adaptor frame: 2->1
   31: /* anonymous */ [fs.js:1662] (this=0x5d74a615 <a WriteStream>#8#,er=0x32408081 <null>,fd=10)
   35: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [native v8natives.js:1597] (this=0x32408091 <undefined>)
   36: arguments adaptor frame: 2->0
   37: done [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:144] (this=0x5d74a9e5 <an OpenReq>#9#,er=0x32408081 <null>,result=10)
   38: done [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:64] (this=0x5d74a9e5 <an OpenReq>#9#,er=0x32408081 <null>,fd=10)
   42: /* anonymous */ [native v8natives.js:1597] (this=0x32408081 <null>)
   43: arguments adaptor frame: 2->0
   45: oncomplete [fs.js:107] (this=0x5d74ab99 <an Object>#10#)
   46: arguments adaptor frame: 2->0
```

... MORE STACKTRACE... TOO MUCH TO PASTE IT ALL HERE ...

```
                 0: 0x5d746321 <JS Function onend>#98#
                 1: 0x5d74b521 <JS Function cleanup>#99#
 #83# 0x3063fd3d: 0x3063fd3d <JS Function>
 #84# 0x5d74a6f1: 0x5d74a6f1 <JS Array[0]>
 #85# 0x5d74abcd: 0x5d74abcd <JS Function g>
          listener: 0x44f2c41d <JS Function>#100#
 #86# 0x5d739b91: 0x5d739b91 <JS Function>
 #87# 0x5d734891: 0x5d734891 <JS Function extractEntry>
 #88# 0x5d73da4d: 0x5d73da4d <JS Function>
 #89# 0x5d73a279: 0x5d73a279 <JS Function onerror>
 #90# 0x5d73a93d: 0x5d73a93d <JS Function>
 #91# 0x5d73dba5: 0x5d73dba5 <JS Function onerror>
 #92# 0x5d73a575: 0x5d73a575 <JS Function g>
          listener: 0x5d73a29d <JS Function onclose>#101#
 #93# 0x5d73486d: 0x5d73486d <JS Function cb>
 #94# 0x5d73dbc9: 0x5d73dbc9 <JS Function cleanup>
 #95# 0x5d73de1d: 0x5d73de1d <JS Array[2]>
                 0: 0x5d73a161 <JS Function>#102#
                 1: 0x5d73dbc9 <JS Function cleanup>#94#
 #96# 0x5d748861: 0x5d748861 <JS Function>
 #97# 0x5d74b4fd: 0x5d74b4fd <JS Function onerror>
 #98# 0x5d746321: 0x5d746321 <JS Function onend>
 #99# 0x5d74b521: 0x5d74b521 <JS Function cleanup>
 #100# 0x44f2c41d: 0x44f2c41d <JS Function>
 #101# 0x5d73a29d: 0x5d73a29d <JS Function onclose>
 #102# 0x5d73a161: 0x5d73a161 <JS Function>
=====================

Trace/breakpoint trap
```

It won't let me paste the entire stack trace, but this is what is happening.  Any ideas what might be going on... other modules are installing fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/27979486/3284355

Comment: I'll give that a try.  I noticed that I was able to install an earlier version of the module that got the job done, but I hate having things not work.